# How to imitate Trello board click & drag to scroll

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a javascript plugin that will allow me to add the same functionality that Trello has on its boards, where you can click on the background, and drag either side to scroll, in a similar way that you would on a mobile with your finger.

I have found some javascript that works, however I also need to be able to click and drag child elements, without the whole board scrolling. In other words, in Trello when you're moving a card between lists, the background doesn't scroll, so there needs to be the ability to add an exception for children elements.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the javascript that works? And point out which one that does not work for you?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/ will probably do the job. If you don't want to scroll the background while you grab/drop an element, try something like 'overflow:hidden' on the body with a selector when you clic (grab) and then set it to auto again when you release the draggable element.

Answer (score 3):

So I was in the process of creating a JSFiddle to give an example of the issue I was having. However as I made it, I decided to actually try and fix it, and it turns out it wasn't that hard.

I've kept the fiddle and saved it, so anyone can see my implementation. It's really very simple.

```js
var curYPos = 0,
  curXPos = 0,
  curDown = false;

$('.wall')[0].addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {

  if (curDown === true) {
    window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollLeft + (curXPos - e.pageX), document.body.scrollTop + (curYPos - e.pageY));
  }
});

$('.wall')[0].addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  if (!$target.hasClass('card')) {
    curDown = true;
    curYPos = e.pageY;
    curXPos = e.pageX;
  }
});
$('.wall')[0].addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  curDown = false;
});

$(function() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    $("#list" + i).sortable({
      connectWith: "#list1, #list2, #list3, #list4, #list5, #list6, #list7, #list8"
    }).disableSelection();
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wall {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0074D9;
  font-size: 0;
  word-spacing: 10px;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
.wall:active {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}
.list {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #FF4136;
  font-size: initial;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.card {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2ECC40;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wall">
  <ul class="list" id="list1">
    <li class="card"></li>
    <li class="card"></li>
    <li class="card"></li>
    <li class="card"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list" id="list2">
    <li class="card"></li>
    <li class="card"></li>
    <li class="card"></li>
    <li class="card"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list" id="list3">
    <li class="card"></li>
    <li class="card"></li>
    <li class="card"></li>
    <li class="card"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list" id="list4">
    <li class="card"></li>
    <li class="card"></li>
    <li class="card"></li>
    <li class="card"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list" id="list5">
    <!-- Empty List -->
  </ul>
  <ul class="list" id="list6">
    <!-- Empty List -->
  </ul>
  <ul class="list" id="list7">
    <!-- Empty List -->
  </ul>
  <ul class="list" id="list8">
    <!-- Empty List -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ro2mtm98/3/

The reason for wanting this is to update the Assembla card wall to add the ability to click and drag to scroll horizontally. They already have their own list dragging javascript (not sure which plugin it uses, pretty sure it's not jQuery sortable. Anyway, using this script I was able to figure out how to make it work on Assembla too